# React props shorthand prettier

Tags: reactjs, prettier, prettier-eslint

There is a `react` codebase, and I would like to prettify it with the following rule:

- Complete the prop shorthands with a value. `shorthand => shorthand={true}`

Current:

```
<Table celled unstackable />
```

Expected:

```
<Table celled={true} unstackable={true} />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an [eslint rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-boolean-value.md)

Just add this to your `eslintrc` `rules` to disable it;

```
react/jsx-boolean-value: off
```

Comment: Thanx your answer, but for my needs this config needed: `'react/jsx-boolean-value': ['error', 'always'],`